# "Discuss" link from google patents

Tags: feature-request

[A recent question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/20376/how-was-the-invention-tested) does not mention the patent to which it is referring. Is it possible that google patents has a link to Ask Patents that does not automatically indicate the patent in question? If so, it is an old problem that stack exchange should be able to fix.

Comment: I kind of believe that the OP just wanted to know how inventions in general were tested, and OP mentioned Downey et al as an inspiration/example, but not necessarily asking about a certain patent. More of bad tagging, and perhaps not fluent in English (use of a specific "the invention" instead of a general "an invention" or "inventions"), and certainly need clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The Google patents link adds a tag with the patent number which some people seem to remove then.

Comment: I just tested the discuss link from a patent on google patents. It did display a suggested tag - the patent number - but that did not automatically appear in the question. I did not see anything telling me about what is on topic or off topic or that I was entering a Q and A site as opposed to a discuss site - having clicked on "discuss" I'm assuming it is a site for random discussions, right?

Comment: It is a pretty annoying link, but provides a lot of traffic. I guess it won't be changed anytime soon.